# Funq: Register the same object multiple times and using an identifier (from session) to resolve them

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, funq

**What I currently have:**

I have a simple dictionary of type `string, DbContext`
I am registering my Dictionary like this

```
container.Register<IDictionary<string, DbContext>>(x => dbContexts).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

and using the dictionary again by simply injecting it in my constructors. So I am always injecting the whole dictionary with every DbContext in it. Later I then get the right DbContext by using an identifier, stored in my usersession. So using a DbContext looks like this:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, DbContext> _dbContexts;
public FooService(IDictionary<string, DbContext> dbContexts)
{
    _dbContexts = dbContexts;
}

public void Bar()
{
    var userSession = GetSession();

    var data = _dbContexts[userSession.TargetConnectionIdentifier].Table.ToList();
}
```

**What I want**

I want to inject only one DbContext into my classes. Using the same property from my session as an identifier. I have seen that Funq offers methods to register instances with a name (e.g. `RegisterAs<>()`). But I am not quite sure how to use them correctly.

```
private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

public FooService(DbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}
```

I want that Funq automatically resolves the right object for me, depending on what value a specific property from my session has.

If anybody knows an answer I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The IOC doesn't have access to the runtime Request context so you couldn't do this within the IOC.

My approach would be to register a factory with the db contexts, e.g:

```
container.Register<IDbContexts>(c => new DbContexts(dbContexts));
```

Then you could have a base class that provides a helper to access the `DbContext` behind a helper, e.g:

```
public class ServiceBase : Service
{
    public IDbContexts DbContexts { get; set; }

    DbContext dbContext;
    public DbContext DbContext => dbContext ?? (dbContext = DbContexts.Get(GetSession()));
}
```

Or you could use Extension methods if you don't want a base class, e.g:

```
public static class MyServiceExtensions
{
    public static DbContext GetDbContext(this Service service)
    {
        var dbContexts = service.TryResolve<IDbContexts>();
        return dbContexts.Get(service.GetSession());
    }
}
```

Then lazily load it in your Service class like:

```
DbContext dbContext;
public DbContext DbContext => dbContext ?? (dbContext = this.GetDbContext());
```